# lots of UDP_IN Blocked errors

Tags: iptables, udp, csf

Since I have reinstalled my OS, I'm getting lots of UDP_IN Blocked errors in my messages log. Can anyone kindly explain what the error say exactly and what I can do to get rid of this error.

```
Aug  8 22:02:19 server kernel: Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:f6:f3:49:7e:0a:54:08:00 SRC=178.162.xxx.xx DST=178.162.xxx.xxx LEN=131 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=11061 PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=111
Aug  8 22:02:22 server kernel: Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ba:08:45:88:fc:a1:08:00 SRC=192.168.x.xx DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=68 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=13132 PROTO=UDP SPT=58878 DPT=1947 LEN=48
Aug  8 22:02:49 server kernel: Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:f6:f3:49:7e:0a:54:08:00 SRC=178.162.xxx.xx DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=131 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=12046 PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=111
Aug  8 22:02:49 server kernel: Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:f6:f3:49:7e:0a:54:08:00 SRC=178.162.xxx.xx DST=178.162.xxx.xxx LEN=131 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=12047 PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=111
Aug  8 22:03:01 server kernel: Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ba:08:45:88:fc:a1:08:00 SRC=192.168.x.xx DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=68 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=13134 PROTO=UDP SPT=58878 DPT=1947 LEN=48
Aug  8 22:03:12 server kernel: Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:62:83:46:e6:0d:15:08:00 SRC=178.162.xxx.xxx DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=115 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5678 DPT=5678 LEN=95
Aug  8 22:03:19 server kernel: Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:f6:f3:49:7e:0a:54:08:00 SRC=178.162.xxx.xx DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=131 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=13070 PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=111
Aug  8 22:03:19 server kernel: Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:f6:f3:49:7e:0a:54:08:00 SRC=178.162.xxx.xx DST=178.162.xxx.xxx LEN=131 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=13071 PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=111
Aug  8 22:03:39 server kernel: Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ba:08:45:88:fc:a1:08:00 SRC=192.168.x.xx DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=68 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=13136 PROTO=UDP SPT=58878 DPT=1947 LEN=48
```

Issuing the iptables-save yields the following:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Fri Aug  8 16:42:05 2014
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [158298:41039552]
:INPUT ACCEPT [131187:38557000]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [79668:17293129]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [79637:17291305]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Aug  8 16:42:05 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Fri Aug  8 16:42:05 2014
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [93313:9541674]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [896:63899]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [896:63899]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Aug  8 16:42:05 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Fri Aug  8 16:42:05 2014
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:ALLOWIN - [0:0]
:ALLOWOUT - [0:0]
:CONNLIMIT - [0:0]
:DENYIN - [0:0]
:DENYOUT - [0:0]
:INVALID - [0:0]
:INVDROP - [0:0]
:LOCALINPUT - [0:0]
:LOCALOUTPUT - [0:0]
:LOGDROPIN - [0:0]
:LOGDROPOUT - [0:0]
:PORTFLOOD - [0:0]
-A INPUT -s 8.8.4.4/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s 8.8.4.4/32 ! -i lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s 8.8.4.4/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s 8.8.4.4/32 ! -i lo -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s 4.2.2.4/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s 4.2.2.4/32 ! -i lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s 4.2.2.4/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s 4.2.2.4/32 ! -i lo -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -j LOCALINPUT 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -j INVALID 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name 22 --rsource 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 250 --hitcount 2 --name 22 --rsource -j PORTFLOOD 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m connlimit --connlimit-above 2 --connlimit-mask 32 -j CONNLIMIT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 46734 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m limit --limit 1/sec -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -m limit --limit 1/sec -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -j LOGDROPIN 
-A OUTPUT -d 8.8.4.4/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -d 8.8.4.4/32 ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -d 8.8.4.4/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -d 8.8.4.4/32 ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -d 4.2.2.4/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -d 4.2.2.4/32 ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -d 4.2.2.4/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -d 4.2.2.4/32 ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -j LOCALOUTPUT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -j INVALID 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 113 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 46734 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 113 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A ALLOWIN -s 37.254.xxx.xxx/32 ! -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A ALLOWOUT -d 37.254.xxx.xxx/32 ! -o lo -j ACCEPT 
-A CONNLIMIT -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset 
-A DENYIN -s 97.77.xxx.xxx/32 ! -i lo -j DROP 
-A DENYOUT -d 97.77.xxx.xxx/32 ! -o lo -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A INVALID -m state --state INVALID -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST FIN,RST -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags PSH,ACK PSH -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ACK,URG URG -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j INVDROP 
-A INVDROP -j DROP 
-A LOCALINPUT ! -i lo -j ALLOWIN 
-A LOCALINPUT ! -i lo -j DENYIN 
-A LOCALOUTPUT ! -o lo -j ALLOWOUT 
-A LOCALOUTPUT ! -o lo -j DENYOUT 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 68 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 111 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 111 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 113 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 113 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 135:139 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 135:139 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 445 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 500 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 500 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 513 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 513 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 520 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 520 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* " 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* " 
-A LOGDROPIN -p icmp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *ICMP_IN Blocked* " 
-A LOGDROPIN -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPOUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *TCP_OUT Blocked* " --log-uid 
-A LOGDROPOUT -p udp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *UDP_OUT Blocked* " --log-uid 
-A LOGDROPOUT -p icmp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *ICMP_OUT Blocked* " --log-uid 
-A LOGDROPOUT -j DROP 
-A PORTFLOOD -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *Port Flood* " 
-A PORTFLOOD -j DROP 
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Aug  8 16:42:05 2014
```

Since I have used CSF for configuring my firewall, I will attach only the lines I have touched.

```
TESTING = "0"

TESTING_INTERVAL = "5"

RESTRICT_SYSLOG = "3"

RESTRICT_SYSLOG_GROUP = "mysyslog"

RESTRICT_UI = "1"

AUTO_UPDATES = "1"

TCP_IN = "20,21,22,25,53,80,110,443,587,995,2222,46734"

TCP_OUT = "20,21,22,25,53,80,110,113,443,2222,46734"

UDP_IN = "20,21,53"

UDP_OUT = "20,21,53,113,123"

ICMP_IN = "1"

ICMP_IN_RATE = "1/s"

ICMP_OUT = "1"

ICMP_OUT_RATE = "0"

IPV6 = "1"

IPV6_ICMP_STRICT = "0"

IPV6_SPI = "1"

TCP6_IN = "20,21,22,25,53,80,110,443,587,995,2222"

TCP6_OUT = "20,21,22,25,53,80,110,113,443,2222"

UDP6_IN = "20,21,53"

UDP6_OUT = "20,21,53,113,123"

ETH_DEVICE = ""

ETH6_DEVICE = ""

ETH_DEVICE_SKIP = ""

USE_CONNTRACK = "0"

SYSLOG_CHECK = "600"

IGNORE_ALLOW = "0"

DNS_STRICT = "0"

DNS_STRICT_NS = "0"

DENY_IP_LIMIT = "200"

DENY_TEMP_IP_LIMIT = "100"

LF_DAEMON = "1"

LF_CSF = "1"
```

Comment: You have a misconfigured firewall. All of the log lines in your question got truncated, so we can't see the port numbers. Without port numbers we cannot say what went wrong. You should also add the actual firewall rules (which you can see with `iptables-save`) to your question.

Comment: @kasperd Thanks for replying. I will edit the post with the firewall rules.

Comment: Those rules are overly complicated. What you need is not just an answer to why you are getting those log messages from the firewall, but rather a thorough code review of your rule set. Not sure if such a review is best suited for `serverfault.com` or `codereview.stackexchange.com`. Did you write your rules in a configuration file to be loaded directly through `iptables-restore`, or is your rule set generated through some tool?

Comment: No, I have installed CSF, following the tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-config-server-firewall-csf-on-ubuntu

Comment: Then including your CSF configuration in the question would be useful. That way it may be possible to say if this poor `iptables` rule set is due to a mistake in the CSF configuration file, or if it is due to CSF not being very good at generating `iptables` rules.

Comment: Do I need to attach the whole content of csf.conf?

Comment: I don't know CSF, thus I can't say if there are parts of the configuration, which are not relevant to your question.

Comment: In the configuration file, you shouldn't open a port both incoming and outgoing over both TCP and UDP, unless you really need all four combinations. But there is other poor structure in the rule set, which I cannot find an explanation for in your configuration file. I'm tempted to say CSF isn't a good tool for generating `iptables` rules.

Comment: You mean I should remove, for instance, ports 20,21,53 in UDP6_IN? BTW, do you propose any alternatives for CSF?

Comment: Are you hosting FTP and DNS servers? If not, then you don't need to permit those ports incoming. FTP runs only on TCP, so no need to permit FTP ports over UDP. DNS OTOH uses both TCP and UDP, so if you need DNS, you need to permit 53 over both TCP and UDP.

Comment: One noteworthy point is that my hostname is different from the name "server" in the logs. Is that OK? because upon installing the Directadmin panel, I changed the hostname but in the log files the name is still the old one.

Comment: Please note that the destination IP is not mine. What does that mean?

Comment: Most of the packets are broadcast packets. MDNS and DHCP are two of the protocols that might be using broadcast packets. Which protocol it actually is, is impossible to say because you excluded that from the log.

Comment: @kasperd I updated the UDP error. The problem was I had not copy/pasted completely.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't run iptables-save since you run CSF and the rules are managed through /etc/csf/csf.conf. The issue is that you don't have port 17500 UDP whitelisted and that's why you're seeing the connections dropped. Those are either infected machines or simply machines running Dropbox (most likely) according to http://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=17500

The same for the other ports, they're simply not whitelisted so that's why you're seeing them as dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wouldn't say your firewall is misconfigured...

Having Drop as default Policy is always fine it just means everything which is not explicitly allowed gets dropped. The only problem is the logging here.

I don't know why, but you have LOGDROP rules defined for some ports (e.g. 520), which means that a connection to (LOGDROPIN) or from (LOGDROPOUT) this port gets dropped AND logged, and that's what causes your log-flooding (you can be happy that it is limited to 30 logs/min by your firewall rules). You can just get rid of those entries as the ports specified are already dropped by your default policy.

Make sure that only ports you actually use are being accepted, because for what I'm seeing here is that your firewall is open for DNS, Mail (110,995,587,25) FTP, SSH, HTTP and HTTPS, also Ports 2222 (could be DirectAdmin) and 46734 (no idea).

So in the right order:

1. Do an iptables-save > /root/firewall
2. Open this file (/root/firewall) and get rid of the logdrop entries (with vi or nano etc.)
3. Do iptables-restore < /root/firewall
4. iptables-save

I don't know which OS you're on but if you didn't configure these firewall rules yourself you might want to load those firewall settings on every startup.

You gotta give some additional information on this, because the answer I gave you will solve your problem but won't help if there is an external program manipulating your firewall (e.g. a GUI-Software). Interesting information would be:

- which OS are you using?
- are you using a special kind of hardware?
- how did you set up the firewall?
- for what purpose do you use the machine?

Comment: Hi. The OS is centos. No special sort of hardware that I am aware of. I have my firewall configured through the use of CSF. I bought the VPS for hosting some production websites, of course.

Comment: Well you gotta find out which services you really need to use, are you really using a DNS service, mailserver etc.? If not, you have to configure your firewall right. I'm not the biggest fan of these GUI-tools that make everything "easier to manage" because obviously they create a lot of garbage in the background... The logging would be useful for network analysis but your server creates a log entry even if a client computer is scanning the network for samba or nfs shares... Normally for the use of websites you would only need ports 80 and 443 + 22 for ssh and MAYBE ports 20-21 for ftp.

Comment: Well, I am using  DNS service, mailserver as well.